# What will happen if we train a model on a dataset sorted by class

Tags: training, mini-batch-gradient-descent

Suppose we have a dataset of two classes (0 and 1) divided into over 12k mini-batches where the first half of the dataset (over 6k mini-batches) belong to class 0, and the other half belongs to class 1. What will happen if a model is trained on this dataset without shuffling the samples?

Comment: Probably the model will overfit to the batches of class 1, which is the one it sees last.

Comment: Is it always a good idea to shuffle data?

Comment: There may be some cases where you specifically want not to shuffle the data but, in general, by default, you should shuffle it.